# Piece wise functions and differentiability

Tags: calculus

I would like to know how a piecewise function and its derivative would look like under these circumstances. Suppose that the function is continuous (and also nice like poly, trig etc) but defined differently for points $\le a$ and point $\gt a $

1) The function is differentiable at $a$. Then the derivative would be continuous at $a$, but would it be differentiable at $a$?

2) The function is continuous at $a$ but not differentiable at $a$. Then the derivative would not be defined at $a$ but defined elsewhere. Is this correct? Also would the left and right limits of the derivative be equal at $a$?

Comment: 2) No, it depends on the function. A continuous function is not necessarily differentiable, by example $f(x):=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be very careful. Consider
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right) & x>0\\0& x\leq 0\end{cases}
$$
This function is differentiable at $0$ since
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h\right|=\lim_{h\to 0^+}h\left|\sin\left(\frac1h\right)\right|=0\text{ and }\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=0.
$$
But
$$
f'(h)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right) & x>0\\0&x\leq 0\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous!

Comment: Thanks for the example, how do you test for continuity at 0 for the derivative function.

Comment: how do you take the limit as x goes to 0 from above of the derivative function. we need to show that the left and right limits are not equal

Comment: @matt observe that $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}[2x\sin(1/x)+\cos(1/x)]\\&=\lim_{x\to 0^+} 2x\sin(1/x)+\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cos (1/x)\\&=0+\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cos (1/x)\end{align}$$ but the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\cos(1/x)$ doesnt exists.

Comment: why is $ \lim_ {x \to 0^+} 2xsin(1/x)=0$

Comment: Also should the derivative be $2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$

Comment: $|sin(1/x)|\leq 1$ yields $0\leq\lim_{x\to 0^+}x|sin(1/x)|\leq\lim_{x\to0^+}x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function:
$$
y= \begin{cases}
x^2 \quad \mbox{for} \quad x\ge0\\
x^3 \quad \mbox{for} \quad x<0\\
\end{cases}
$$
this function is differentiable at $x=0$ ( and for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$) but its derivative is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$